# Read and Edit a single line in a text file with Python

Tags: python

I have spent ages looking at solutions on here, but as someone new to Python I am getting stuck. I think my problem is easy to solve but any help would be great.

If I have a text file that has the following in it:

```
Name1, 12, 32
Name2, 49, 43
Name3, 43, 13
Name4, 43, 53
```

I know I want to replace the second number of Name2 from 43 to say 10. How would I display Name2 data in Python, edit it and then put it back into the text file?

Also it there anyway of getting Python to tell you which line in the text file Name2 is on (e.g. It is on line 2)?

Please - simplest solution!!! Thank you .

Comment: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print where `Name1` appears:

```
import csv

with open("path/to/file") as infile:
    for i, (name, *data) in enumerate(csv.reader(infile), 1):
        if name != "Name1": continue
        print("'Name1' found on line", i)
```

To replace the data associated with it:

```
with open("path/to/file") as infile, open("path/to/output", 'w') fout:
    outfile = csv.writer(fout)
    for i, (name, first, second) in enumerate(csv.reader(infile), 1):
        if name == "Name1":
            second -= 33
        outfile.writerow([name, first, second])
```